# Spring import config from another project, transient dependencies, ClassNotFound

Tags: java, spring, maven

Here's the situation. I have 2 projects.

### Project A

- Imports mongo-java-driver
- Has a ConfigurationA class that defines a Bean like so:

  ```
  public @Bean MongoDatabase getMongoDatabase() {
      MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
      return client.getDatabase("mydb");
  }
  ```

### Project B

- Imports Project A

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>project-a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Has a ConfigurationB class that imports ConfigurationA
- Does *not* have import for mongo-java-driver

When I try to run project B I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase
```

If I add an explicit import to Project B for mongo-java-driver, it works fine.

My question is: Why do I need the import in Project B? Is there anything I can do to prevent this? I don't want Project B to know about the dependencies in Project A.

Comment: Can you share how the dependency of Project A in the Project B pom.xml was written?

Comment: See my edit. It's a vanilla dependency.

Comment: Is this a multi-module project? Are you using M2Eclipse? Did you clean and reinstalled everything and retested?

Comment: If is a multi-module project you should probably use `${project.version}` inside the `version` tag dependency. Maybe is a versions problem...